# Scheduling: Is is a Physical layer functionality or a Data(MAC) layer functionality or is it both?

Tags: communication, wireless, mac

Fellas,

When we use the term SCHEDULING in wired/wireless communication, does it relate to a physical layer functionality or a Data (MAC) layer functionality or to both?

Answer (score 1):

MAC Functions:
Physical addressing (MAC addressing) LAN switching (packet switching), including MAC filtering, Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) and Shortest Path Bridging (SPB) Data packet queuing or scheduling Store-and-forward switching or cut-through switching Quality of Service (QoS) control Virtual LANs (VLAN)

PHY functions:
Bit-by-bit or symbol-by-symbol delivery
Providing a standardized interface to physical transmission media,Modulation
Line coding
Bit synchronization in synchronous serial communication
Start-stop signalling and flow control in asynchronous serial communication
Circuit switching
Multiplexing,Carrier sense and collision detection utilized by some level 2 multiple access protocols
Equalization filtering, training sequences, pulse shaping and other signal processing of physical signals
Forward error correction[5] for example bitwise convolutional coding
Bit-interleaving and other channel coding
The physical layer is also concerned with:

Bit rate
Point-to-point, multipoint or point-to-multipoint line configuration
Physical network topology, for example bus, ring, mesh or star network
Serial or parallel communication
Simplex, half duplex or full duplex transmission mode
Autonegotiation,

see wiki for each layer.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduling of when to send data is part of framing which occurs in the data layer.  Of course the parameters of the physical layer come into play in those decisions (can we send and receive simultaneously? what throughput is possible?) but the data layer makes the decision.